# Accessing file within Safari extension from app

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7-beta4, safari-content-blocker

I'm building safari content blocker (xcode 7 beta 4).

In app I use `SFContentBlockerManager.reloadContentBlockerWithIdentifier` to actualize `blockerList.json` file, but I can't access it to rewrite with new rules.

```
let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, [.AllDomainsMask], true).first!
let file = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("blockerList.json"))
try String(contentsOfURL: file, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

throws exception, about `file not found`.

Also it seems that `beginRequestWithExtensionContext` still not called (no breakpoint or NSLog worked). So - I also can't load updated json file through extension code.

Comment: Have you tested the "blockerList.json"  file? is it present in  documents of the App?